# Spacing in HTML Email on Android GMAIL App

Tags: android, html, email, gmail

There is extra white space on my HTML email between the header.png and the body.png image (their table rows, actually). I cant for the life of me figure out why this is happening. It only happens on Gmail for Android and not on Gmail for Iphone. Here is the code:

```
<body topmargin="0">
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing:0; border: none; border: 1px solid #b76f49">
    <tr>
        <td width="600" style="display:block !important;">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing:0;">
                <tr>
                    <td width="600" style="line-height:0;">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing:0;line-height:0;font-size:1px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="17" style="line-height:0;min-width:17px;">
                                    <img src="headerleft.png" width="17" style="display:block !important; line-height:0;font-size:1px;" align="absbottom">
                                </td>
                                <td width="567" style="line-height:0;min-width:567px;">
                                    <img alt="" border="0" width="567" src="header.png" style="display:block !important; line-height:0;font-size:1px;" align="absbottom">
                                </td>
                                <td width="16" style="line-height:0;min-width:16px;">
                                    <img src="headerright.png" width="16" style="display:block !important; line-height:0;font-size:1px;" align="absbottom">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="600" style="display:block !important;">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing:0;">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="17" style="border-right:3px solid #b76f49; min-width:17px; font-size:1px;">
                                    <img src="bodyleft.png" width="17" border="0" style="display:block !important; line-height:0; font-size:1px;">
                                </td>
                                <td width="561">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="561" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing:0;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="20" style="font-size:1px;">
                                                &nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="357" valign="top" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px; font-color: #000;">
                                                <p style="font-family:Arial; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; color:#004685;">HEader</p>
                                                Hello,<br><br>

                                                <ul>
                                                    <li></li>
                                                    <li></li>
                                                    <li></li>
                                                    <li></li>
                                                </ul>
                                                &nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="184" style="min-width:184px;">
                                                <img src="bodyrightimage.png" width="170" height="400" border="0" align="right" style="font-size: 1px; line-height:0px; display:block!important;">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td width="30" style="border-left:3px solid #b76f49;min-width:30px;">
                                    <img src="bodyright.png" height="400" width="16" border="0" style="display:block !important; line-height:0; font-size: 1px;">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: HTML email is not fun. Look into https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/

Comment: Have you tried removing the `!important` after `display: block` ?

Answer (score 0):

HTML counts line breaks as whitespace, so if you're using table cells (ick) for layout purposes, then this code:

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <img ... />
                 ^---line break here
   </td>
^^^---indentation whitespace here
   <td>
      <img ... />
   </d>
</tr>
```

will be rendered as

```
[img] [img]
     ^----linebreak+indentation as whitespace
```

Simple solution: don't put your `</td>` on a separate line:

```
<tr>
   <td><img ../></td>
   <td><img ../></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I will give it a try, but this is for an HTML email. WHat else would I use a table cell for???

Comment: tabular data? using tables for layout went out of style long ago when css was introduced.

Comment: Have you ever coded an HTML email with only CSS and DIVS?

Comment: @MarcB Unfortunately for proper HTML to be rendered in email programs (a large percentage of which are still ancient MS Outlooks), you need to use code like 1999. There is limited support for proper CSS like in the web.